# react-router-dom > NavLink > multiple activeClassName?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

is it possible to have multiple activeClassName in NavLink component form react-router-dom?

I have Navbar with NavLinks and I need to add active class to the elements, with hasActiveClass === true, to render specific content. But also I need another active class (for example 'iconActive') to toggle icons, when the link is active. So the code is like that:

```
const MainNavComponent = () => (
  <nav className="nav">
          {menu.map(
            ({ ...props }, index) =>
                <TileNav key={index} {...props} />
          )}
  </nav>
);

const TileNav = ({ to, hasActiveClass, exact, img, activeImg }) => {
  // this is not working:
   const isActive = element.className.contains('active');
   const imgSrc = isActive ? activeImg : img;

  return (
    <NavLink
      to={to}
      activeClassName={
        hasActiveClass ? 'active' : ''
      }
      className="tile-nav__link"
      exact={exact}
    >
      <div className="tile-nav">
        {isActive ? (
          <img className="tile-nav__img" src={activeImg} alt="Menu icon" />
        ) : (
          <img className="tile-nav__img" src={img} alt="Menu icon" />
        )}
      </div>
    </NavLink>

  )
};

and the data came from there:

const menu = [
  {
    to: '/',
    img: menuAccessIcon,
    activeImg: menuAccesActiveIcon,
    exact: true,
    hasActiveClass: false
  },
  {
    to: urls.someUrl.url,
    img: menuSomeIcon,
    activeImg: menuSomeActiveIcon,
    exact: true,
    hasActiveClass: true,
    hideForQuasiUser: true
  },
  {
    to: urls.someurl.url,
    img: menuSomeIcon,
    activeImg: menuSomeActiveIcon,
    exact: true,
    hasActiveClass: true,
    hideForQuasiUser: true
  },
  {
    to: urls.someUrl.url,
    img: menuIcon,
    activeImg: menuActiveIcon,
    exact: true,
    hasActiveClass: true
  }
];
```

I tried also add another key to each object:
hasActiveIcon: true

and then:

```
  activeClassName={
    hasActiveClass ? 'active' : '',
    hasActiveIcon && 'activeIcon'
  }
```

but it still not working, because I got only second active class in DOM :(
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix like this by using `template strings`

```
activeClassName={`${hasActiveClass ? "active" : ""} ${hasActiveIcon ? "activeIcon" : ""}`}
```

Comment: Yeah, right. But how can I pass src to img depends on which className (active or not) is?

Comment: ` src={isActive  ? activeImg : img}`

Comment: This was my first idea, but it's not working. isActive is undefined. I can't get it by element.className.contains("active")

Comment: ` src={hasActiveClass ? activeImg : img}`